# How can I make an updating timer on an existing window made with Arcade in Python?

Tags: python, arcade

I have been creating a project in arcade that has a race car on screen that dodges obstacles and tries reaching the finish line with as fast as time as possible. I have seen other questions that have been answered in creating a new window with a timer but I can not seem to figure out how to add to my existing race car screen a timer that updates and then stops when the race car hits the finish line. Any help would be much appreciated!

Here is the main class with current code:

"""
Show a timer on-screen.

"""
from game.point import Point
import arcade
import datetime

```
class Timer():
"""
Main application class.
"""
def __init__(self):
    self.output = str

def timer_draw(self, total_time):
    """ Use this function to draw everything to the screen. """

    # Calculate minutes
    minutes = int(total_time) // 60

    # Calculate seconds
    seconds = int(total_time) % 60

    # Figure out our output
    self.output = f"Time: {minutes:02d}:{seconds:02d}"
```

Seperate class:

```
def on_update(self, delta_time):
    self._cue_action("update")
    self.total_time += delta_time
    self.timer.timer_draw(self.total_time)
```

Seperate class:

```
def timer(self, output):

    arcade.draw_text(f'Timer:', 550, 550, arcade.color.BLACK, 30)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `time` lib for measuring race duration.
Here is the small example (green circle is "car" and yellow line is "finish line"):

Code:

```
import time
import arcade

class Game(arcade.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(400, 300)
        self.time_start = time.time()
        self.time_elapsed = 0
        self.x = 0

    def on_draw(self):
        arcade.start_render()
        arcade.draw_text(str(self.time_elapsed), 170, 260, arcade.color.RED, 28)
        arcade.draw_line(300, 0, 300, 300, arcade.color.GOLD, 5)
        arcade.draw_circle_filled(self.x, 140, 20, arcade.color.GREEN)

    def update(self, delta_time):
        if self.x < 320:
            self.x += 2
            self.time_elapsed = round(time.time()-self.time_start, 1)
            
Game()
arcade.run()
```

Output:

[image]